# How to use multiple pixel ids in one react native app for tracking?

Tags: react-native, facebook-sdk-4.0, facebook-pixel, react-native-fbsdk, react-native-fbsdk-next

I have a app in react native. I want to track facebook pixel events on 2 different pixel accounts. I am using react-native-fbsdk-next

I have tried adding
`Settings.setAppID('PIXEL_1'); Settings.setAppID('PIXEL_2');`
but not working. As default pixel configuration is been added in android manifest and info.plist:

AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <application ...>
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ClientToken"       android:value="@string/facebook_client_token"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
...
...
</application>
```

Info.plist

```
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>PIXEL_APP_ID</string>
<key>FacebookClientToken</key>
<string>PIXEL_CLIENT_TOKEN</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define the Facebook id programmatically. So you do not need to setup the facebook id manifest or info.plist file.

Android

```
FacebookSdk.setApplicationId("123456789");
```

iOS

```
[FBSettings setDefaultAppID: @"123456789"];
```

At last, when you need to change it you have to create a native bridge to update that facebook id.
Please use react-native- document.
[link](https://reactnative.dev/docs/communication-ios)

Comment: But how to define multiple fb IDs?

Comment: When you start the application. Default FB id is initialised when you want to change fb id and you have to create interface to native code to update FB id.